# Importing exported project templates in Visual studio does not restore packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I created an project template according to [microsofts docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2017). The project itself requires 3 packages that I installed from Nuget. However upon importing the project/creating a new project with the template results in the packages not being found  Nuget settings are set to "download missing packages" and if I hover my using statements, I only get the option to remove them, not download them. According to Package manager, the packages are restored but the compiler cannot even find for example the System namespace.

Comment: If packages are installed but just not downloaded they'll always restore during build (nuget restore will be called automatically)

Comment: What project? Which Visual Studio version? With the latest MSBuild project format, used in .NET Core and Standard projects (at leas(, packages are defined in the `csproj` file itself. No other setting is needed or used

Comment: Visual studio 2017, using  .Net Core(Class Library). I double checked the .csproj file and the packages are there.